# Chrome Webstore is broken (Image Decode failed)

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, chrome-extension

my webstore in Chrome is broken. 
I already purged chrome and reinstalled it but nothing new.

It says image decode failed, when I want to install new extensions.
ALso every picture is broken. 
I have a dual boot and no problem with Chrome under Windows.

Under Linux I can not install any extensions with and without sync with my Account. 
I also used the incognito mode but it still won't work.

Do you have any advice?

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Everything else is up to date.

[image: Screenshot from the store]

Comment: Hi and welcome! Are you using any ad-blocker extensions?  If so, which extension, and which extension version, and which Chrome version are you using?

Comment: @unforgettableid I am using Chrome 70 for Linux. 
And deleted all extensions I had. Also, I set chrome completely back and cleared the cache etc. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: edited. Found the solution.

Here was my problem:

It was because some google content was blocked in my hosts.

You can check if it is the same for you.

how to edit hosts: sudo nano /etc/hosts

Comment: @Brainoverflow edited my answer. Found my fix.

Comment: I have some google content blocked as well like advertises etc. Should I delete all google files from the list?

Comment: I would experiment. 
- Save the hosts file in a backup txt file.
- Start removing the google hosts until you delete the only ones that you don't need. 

Looking up the hosts file on google would also probably save you time.

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer about hosts helped me: I worked under vpn and when I turned off vpn the extension was added

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
To find the cause, I opened the chrome web store with VPN, and found everything is normal. Like images loaded, and extensions installed without any issue.

Which proves that it is not a Chrome issue but ISP / network issue, who accidentally blocking these resources.

Call your internet service provider to unblock those resources.

Comment: The solution above fixed it for me. I blocked some of the google content

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings in Chrome and enable redirects...Boom the issue is resolved...